# Unable to download SQL database from server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I´ve been asked to download some data using pyodbc however I´m having some problems, here is the code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
    
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=database.net;"
                      "Database=Spectrometry;"
                      "uid=user;pwd=password")
    
Users = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Users", conn)
Activity = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Activity", conn)
```

After executing this I get:

> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager]
> Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)
> (SQLDriverConnect)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you may have made a tiny mistake will writing the code. Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Linux) and and example available.

I belieleve that it should be :

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
    
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver=SQL Server;"  #  <= No {} needed
                      "Server=database.net;"
                      "Database=Spectrometry;"
                      "uid=user;pwd=password")
    
Users = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Users", conn)
Activity = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Activity", conn)
```

Another thing I might add is, have you checked the available odbc drivers available on your set up ?
I suggest you run:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()
```

It should give you a list of available drivers name (The name you need to specify on the connect method). If the list is empty you might want to look into how to install odbc driver on your environment.
For sql server version 15 they are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the error keeps appearing. I have a list of 6 drivers, one of which is called  'SQL Server'. Should I install `SQL Server Native Client` or one of the most recent ODBC Driver for SQL Server? Ty

Comment: are you on linux ? If so I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Linux
It contains step by step tutorial on setting everything up

Comment: (linux only) what does `cat /etc/odbcinst.ini` ?
On my side as I have a fresh install, I see `[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1
UsageCount=1`

Answer (score 0):

**Connection strings**

Connecting to named instance instance1 using the instance name:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=192.106.0.102\instance1;DATABASE=master;UID=sql2008;PWD=password123')
```

Connecting to named instance using TCP/IP using the port number 1443:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=192.106.0.102,1443;DATABASE=master;UID=sql2008;PWD=password123')
```

pyodbc.connect() supports keywords, I think these are easier to read and you don't have to do any string formatting if you're using variables for connection string attributes:

Named instance:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}',
                               server='192.106.0.102\instance1',
                               database='master',
                               uid='sql2008',pwd='password123')
```

TCP/IP port:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}',
                               server='192.106.0.102,1443',
                               database='master',
                               uid='sql2008',pwd='password123')
```